# React Native: Update UI based on Rest API CALL

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native and trying to update the screen based on the data from REST call and I can see the logs from `render()` getting printed but the text input is not being created.

I read up few documents. I used
https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/async-await-with-react-lifecycle-methods-802e7760d802

as a baseline. The API and parsing works if I put it as a independent function but when I am trying to parse and add the data in the view it fails.
Can anyone help, what I'm doing wrong, or am I even on the right path?

CODE:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, ScrollView, Text, Linking, Platform, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
            
export default class DetailScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {}
    setStateAsync(state) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.setState(state, resolve)
        });
    }
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    }
            
            
    async componentDidMount() {
        var response = await fetch('https://www.merckmanuals.com/custom/infobutton/search?mainSearchCriteria.v.ot=Anemia&holder.assignedEntity.n=Igedla&holder.assignedEntity.certificateText=Summer@020', {
        method: 'GET', });
        var parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;
        var xml = await response.text()
        var okdss ='';
        parseString(xml, function (err, resssult) { okdss = resssult; });
        var thisone = Object.keys(okdss).map(key => ({[key]:okdss[key]}));
        await this.setStateAsync({data: thisone}) 
    }
                  
    render() {
        return (
              <View style={styles.container}>
    
    {this.state?.data?.map((item) => {
            console.log('feed id:' + item.feed.id);
            var abc1 = item.feed.entry.map((abc2) => {
            console.log('entry id:' + abc2.id);
            var abc3 = abc2.title.map((abc4) => {
            console.log('feed.entry title:' + abc4._);
            <Text>{abc4._}</Text>
            });
            var abc5 = abc2.summary.map((abc6) => { 
            console.log('feed.entry summary:' + abc6._);
            <Text>{abc6._}</Text>
            });
            });
            })}
    
              </View>
            )
          }
            
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
render() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>

       {this.state?.data?.map((item) => {
         console.log('feed id:' + item.feed.id);
         return item.feed.entry.map((abc2) => {
            console.log('entry id:' + abc2.id);
            var abc3 = abc2.title.map((abc4) => {
              console.log('feed.entry title:' + abc4._);
              return <Text>{abc4._}</Text>
            });
            var abc5 = abc2.summary.map((abc6) => { 
              console.log('feed.entry summary:' + abc6._);
              return <Text>{abc6._}</Text>
            });
            return (
              <>
                {abc3()}
                {abc5()}
              </>
            )
          });
       })}

     </View>
   )
 }
```

Comment: where exactly? can you please share detail code/exact location?